# How to wrap a method that returns an optional <T> with fromNullable?

Tags: java, guava, option-type

I have a method that I don't own that is returning null but return type is Optional<Boolean>.  When I call x.IsPresent() it throws (scenario #2).  I tried wrapping the method in a fromNullable but I get a type mismatch (screen shot below).  How can I fix so IsPresent() doesn't throw?

```
import com.google.common.base.Optional;

private Optional<Boolean> get_I_dontHaveControlOverThisMethod () {
    return null;  // Ooops!
}

// Compile error? ----------------------->  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
Optional<Boolean> x = Optional.fromNullable(get_I_dontHaveControlOverThisMethod());   
// (#1) Optional<Boolean> x = Optional.fromNullable(null);  // <- this work fine
// (#2) Optional<Boolean> x = get_I_dontHaveControlOverThisMethod();
if (x.isPresent()) {   // <- this blows up!  NPE when (#2) runs
    // non-null good value;
}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't use any of Java 8 though, you should probably use the Java 8 Optional instead of the Guava Optional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
Optional<Boolean> x = get_I_dontHaveControlOverThisMethod();
if(x == null) x = Optional.absent();
```

If you are calling such methods quite often, you can wrap it into function:

```
static <T> Optional<T> safeOptional(Optional<T> optional) {
    return optional == null ? Optional.absent() : optional;
}
```

And use:

```
Optional<Boolean> x = safeOptional(get_I_dontHaveControlOverThisMethod());
```

Comment: very cool!  I like that approach!  it would be nice if this was built into the library because it seems to me that having to check Optional <T> variables for null defeats the entire purpose of the Optional Semantics.  However, just goes to show you that a 3rd party method that says it will return Optional<T> you can never trust it.

Answer (score 3):

The type of `Optional.fromNullable(get_I_dontHaveControlOverThisMethod())` would be `Optional<Optional<Boolean>>`, not `Optional<Boolean>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can "unwrap" or "flatten" the `Optional<Optional<Boolean>>` with `.or(Optional.<Boolean>absent())`:

```
Optional<Boolean> x = Optional.fromNullable(get_I_dontHaveControlOverThisMethod())
            .or(Optional.<Boolean>absent());
```